# Conditional list rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this sidebar component and I want to show the sidebar elements differently if the user is a simple user or is admin.

I have this **isManager** boolean saved in my state.
If isManage is true, I want to loop on the complete **links** array.
If isManager is false, I want to loop on the same array but without the last three elements (a simple array.splice).

But I get confused with JSX syntax and I don't know where to put the condition.

```
return (
    <div className="flex-item--fill flex--column scops-sidebar-content-container">
      <ul>
        {links.map((link) => (
          <li
            key={link.id}
            className="pad-half--left"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: `${
                activeTabId === link.id ? '#4065d0' : 'var(--color-primary)'
              }`,
            }}
          >
            <button
              className="btn--plain full-width align--left unpad"
              style={{ color: 'white' }}
              onClick={(e) => tabHandler(e, link.id)}
            >
              {link.name}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

This is my component. Thanks a lot

Comment: Before you return your JSX element inside of the actual function, you could use your `isManager` flag to create a new array of `links` to render, where you perform your splice on the existing `links` array, so you can remove the last 3 links that you don't want if the `isManager` flag is false.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Michael P. Bazos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69750411/974186) answer:

I usually move as much logic as I can outside JSX, because it makes JSX harder to read and you might accidentially change logic by just editing view things.

Thus I would make the decision just before the JSX.

```
 const linksToRender = isManager ? links : links.slice(0, -3));

 return (
   <div className="flex-item--fill flex--column scops-sidebar-content-container">
     <ul>
       {linksToRender.map((link) => (
         // ....
       ))}
     </ul>
   </div>
);
```

Comment: Totally agree. Makes it much easier to read when the JSX is as branch-less as possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
{(isManager ? links : links.slice(0, -3)).map(link => 
   (...JSX FOR LINK...)
)}
```

`links.slice(0, -3)` returns the array minus the last three elements.
E.g.:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].slice(0, -3)` => `[1, 2]`

Note the we are using `slice`, and not `splice` which would mutate the links array as it deletes elements from it.

Note2: I wanted to show the minimal path to reach the answer. Naturally, for better clarity, you can add a line of code and store the result of the condition to a local variable, as suggested by René Link (whose name fits perfectly the answer)

Comment: You put that condition inside the return?

Comment: Exactly where you have your map function, under the `<ul>` tag

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos `links` must bу mapped too, so we need something like this:

`renderLinks = isManager ? links : links.slice(0, -3));`

```renderLinks.map(link =>   (...JSX FOR LINK...))```

Comment: i want to map the links if isManager, and sliced links if !isManager

so i guess it's better to put it outside the jsx return

Comment: So this is what is done, as the `map` function applies to whichever array comes out of the conditional expression evaluation.

Comment: Ok got it now, sorry. I like your solution too